# Reference request: complex K-theory as a commutative ring spectrum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy

Does anyone know of a point-set level model for complex K-theory as a commutative ring spectrum?

For real $K$-theory
I know of "[A symmetric ring spectrum representing KO-theory](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82162879.pdf)" by Michael Joachim (Topology, 40(2) 2001).

Comment: I think Joachim's proof works verbatim by taking complex vector spaces instead of real vector spaces.

Comment: Schwede's symmetric spectra book project (http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/SymSpec-v3.pdf, see Example 1.20) constructs _ku_ and _KU_ as commutative rings in symmetric spectra.